# Dúvidas sobre Notice Undefined variable

Tags: php

o que significa este aviso 
Notice: Undefined variable: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php on line 7
detalhe o login existe

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
$login = $_POST['login']; 
} else { 
echo "Login Vazio."; 
} 

$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='{$login}' "); 
$linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria desta forma:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='{$login}' ") or print mysql_error(); 
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql);  
} else { 
    echo "Login Vazio."; 
}
```

Desta forma conseguiremos saber se o login realmente existe e conseguiremos também saber se há algum erro de mysql na consulta.

Com base nisso, saberemos por onde concertar o erro, se ainda houver.

Comment: Sim ainda a um erro não acessa o login mas tem dados nele , poderá ser erro do banco de dados

Comment: qual é o erro que deu?

Comment: Undefined variable: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php on line 7  Nisto aparece o texto dizendo que o login esta vazio, mas tem o cod de login no banco de dados

Comment: modifique conforme o André sugeriu..

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque você provavelmente está enviando um formulário sem `method="POST"` ou o atributo `name=""` no `input` está errado.

Pra funcionar o `<form>` deve ser algo como:

```
<form method="POST" action="perfil.php">
   <input type="text" name="login" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

No entanto pela sua query eu suspeito que você não esteja usando um form e sim um método GET, provavelmente um link com `<a href="perfil.php?login=usuario">`

Links não usam método POST, eles usam método GET, então o correto é isto:

```
$login = NULL; //Declaramos a variavel

if(false === empty($_GET['login'])){//Se existir define em login e não for vazia
    $login = $_GET['login'];
} else {//Se não existir ou for vazia emite um erro
    echo "Login Vazio."; 
}

if ($login) {//Se a variável existir executa a query
    $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='{$login}'") or print mysql_error(); 
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
}
```